# Can I control the android device screen on in the PowerManagerService.java?

Tags: android, controls, screen

I have a question on the control of android device's screen on.
What I want to implement on android framework is that:
depend on specific application, I can control the screen to be on or not.
That is to say, if I don't want some application, let's say the AngerBirds, to make the 
screen from state off to on, can I do it?

From the source code of PowerManagerService.java:
I found there is one line of code:

```
 `policy.screenTurningOn(mScreenOnListener);`
```

so, is this the code to turn on the screen?

Then if I add some condition here, such as, if the current command of turnning on the screen is from
the application AngryBird, then I just ignore, and make the screen keep state off.
is this possible?

If possible, then can I get the Application context and the reason of turnning on the screen?